# JQuery ajaxForm to angularJS

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I would like to 'translate' a jquery function into AngularJS. Here's the code

```
function uploadAvatar(){
$('#pushingImageForm').ajaxForm({
success: function(response){
  var newSrc = // code for new image source
  $(".user-img img").attr("src", newSrc);
}
 }).submit();
}
```

Is there any way to convert that or I have to use the [$http](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24http) ? Thank you.

Comment: no conversion tool is available you to have use $resource or $http to convert

Comment: Ok, thanks Ajay. Is there a good tutorial or example that might apply to my case?

Comment: may be this link solve your problem :http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$http